# "There are five basic types of adverbs in the English language, namely that of ...", what does that refer to here?

Tags: meaning

A [post](https://www.myenglishteacher.eu/blog/types-of-adverb/) explains adverbs in this way

> Adverbs provide a deeper description of a verb within any sentence. There are five basic types of adverbs in the English language, namely **that** of Manner, Time, Place, Frequency, and Degree.

What does **that** refer to here?

Comment: It refers to "adverb" (or "type of adverb") but it is very poorly worded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"That" refers to the aforementioned *types of adverbs*.

> There are five basic types of adverbs in the English language, namely that of Manner, Time, Place, Frequency, and Degree.

Without "that of", the sentence would be incorrect, because 'Manner, Time, Place, Frequency, and Degree' are not the names of adverbs themselves - they are *types of* adverb.

It is in effect saying that there are *adverbs of manner, adverbs of time* etc.